# I'd like to sync two folders for missing files ignoring the path

Tags: file-synchronization

I'd like to sync two folders in a way that both folders will have the same files after the sync but not necessarily the same folder structure. The sync only occurs if the a file in the first folder is not present in the second folder folder in any path (and vice versa), in this case it can create the same path in the second folder that is present in this file in the first folder. But if the file in the first folder is present in any path in the second folder, even though this path is different, they don't sync. Any recommendations?